# measure time in simulink

Tags: matlab, time, simulink

I'm trying to create a sorting algorithm in simulink.
You can't use matlab-function blocks because it's a recursive function, so I have to use the S-function builder.
Now I want to know how long the algorithm takes for a different inputrange.
This is my code:

```
clock_t begin = clock();

sort(x,0,999);

clock_t einde = clock();

*time = (einde - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

The sorting function works fine. But the output for time is the first element in the sorted array. Which makes no sense!?

Anyone knows what might cause the problem?
btw tic;toc; doesn't work in simulink, you have to write your own code.

Comment: Can't you just simulate the model from an m-file using `sim()` and then use tic; toc; or `timeit()`?

Comment: Yes but this includes the time to compile the model. I want the time of a specific function.

Comment: Did you try to profile your model? http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/examples/introduction-to-profiling-models.html

Comment: Yes, but this only works when the model runs on the host. The goal is to deploy it to a raspberry pi. In that case, Simulink can't produce a profiler.

Comment: May be replace temporarily sort with something else like sleep to check whether time computation works fine?

Comment: You need to show us more code.  Are you sure that you are outputting the time variable (and not, accidenttly, the first element of the sort)?